How to prohibit exception messages from being redirected to the terminal?
I'm writing launch.json in VS Code. I learned some advices and try to replace my gdb location with another one when writing C++ code (I think this may be the reason I receive the results I described in the title).
But when I start debugging, the message of exception was shown on the terminal, which has never been there before.

And the GDB line went like this:

Here's information about two useful files: (I add all the translation by comments for reading better)
launch.json
{
    // 使用 IntelliSense 了解相关属性。 //Use IntelliSence to know more.
    // 悬停以查看现有属性的描述。//Hover to check the description of that feature.
    // 欲了解更多信息，请访问: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    // For more information, visit: xxx
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) 启动 ", //(gdb)start
            "type": "cppdbg",
            
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe 生成活动文件",//"C/C++: g++.exe generating active file"
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": 
            "D:/MinGW/mingw64_13/x86_64-13.2.0-release-win32-seh-ucrt-rt_v11-rev0/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "为 gdb 启用整齐打印", //Using neat print for gdb
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "将反汇编风格设置为 Intel", //Set the disassembly style to Intel
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                //This is a part added by myself for some usages.
                {
                    "description": "在调试中跳过属于std命名空间的函数(已编译过)", 
                    "text": "skip -rfu std::.*",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}

tasks.json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe 生成活动文件", //C/C++: g++.exe generating active files
            "command": "D:\\MinGW\\mingw64_13\\x86_64-13.2.0-release-win32-seh-ucrt-rt_v11-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "调试器生成的任务。" //tasks generated by the debugger
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}


You are not catching the exception in main(), so it escapes and terminates the process. Why would you not expect it to display in the terminal? If you don't want that, then catch it in main().

Sorry. I haven't met this situation before( I didn't catch exceptions in main() in the past, and the exception message weren't shown on the terminal) So I think it can't help me

This is the correct behavior. If you don't catch an exception your program is has to terminate because of the exception. Whether it dies with or without the message is up to the compiler. However as a software developer I would always prefer it to tell me the reason for ending the process over hiding that from me.

@drescherjm "Whether it dies with or without the message is up to the compiler" - well, not the compiler itself, but whatever environment is running the compiled exe. In this case, the environment being used clearly knows how to decypher the exception, so it does so and displays the error message.
